# How to fetch only date from timestamp through PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, date, timestamp

I want to fetch old date as well not only current date stored in Timestamp,i used date() function but it only return current date and time.

Comment: what is the Timestamp storing ?

Comment: its storing like this 2018-05-25 08:50:22.114432

Comment: Show me your code

Comment: $review_date=$data['review_date'];
echo $review_date=date('d M,Y');

it returning current date mean today date not previous one stored in timestamp column

Comment: if its about database, it can store only a single value at a time. Once you save a new value, old value gets overwritten. If you elaborate about the database itself, then probably u may get

Comment: no,when new user enter his review then new current date stored very next row

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work for you

```
$review_date=$data['review_date'];
$review_date=date('d M,Y', strtotime($review_date));
```

Comment: Getting this warning

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in C:\xampp\htdocs\ESTSYD\Directory Website\listing-details.php on line 729

Comment: @MudassirAbbasi You have to select timezone to remove error by date_default_timezone_set or you may set date.timezone in php.ini to fix this globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `strtotime` and `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. I prefer the second one.

```
$timestamp = '2018-05-25T10:00:00';
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTH:i:s');

echo $oDate->format('Y-m-d');
```